# Incorrect redirection from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all `non-www` and all `non-https` to `https://www` URL.

I have a .htaccess containing the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

That is working for the root path:

```
OK https://www.mywebsite.com => https://www.mywebsite.com
OK http://mywebsite.com => https://www.mywebsite.com
OK https://mywebsite.com => https://www.mywebsite.com
OK http://www.mywebsite.com => https://www.mywebsite.com
```

But there is (kind of) a bug when I try to go in sub-folder:

```
OK https://www.mywebsite.com/tmp => https://www.mywebsite.com/tmp
KO https://mywebsite.com/tmp => https://www.mywebsite.com/tmp/tmp
KO http://www.mywebsite.com/tmp => https://www.mywebsite.com/tmp/tmp
KO http://mywebsite.com/tmp => https://www.mywebsite.com/tmp/tmp
```

As you can see, the sub-folder is appended once again and it gives a 404 Error.

How could I fix my .htaccess rules to get the expected redirections ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is use of `%{REQUEST_URI}$1` which is adding captured value i.e. URI at the end of `REQUEST_URI`.

Also as an optimization you can combine both rules into one like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.